Crestron CH5 HTML SIMPL - How to add events after connection?
After a connection has been made with Crestron's WebXPanel library I want to be able to immediately call a function after that gets the state of a symbol.
The problem unfortunately cant be fixed by DOMContentloaded, as Crestron WebXPanel library gets loaded in after the DOM is initialized. Meaning CrComLib.getState will always return null.
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
let lang = CrComLib.getState('s','Settings.Language.current');

console.log('Language current: ',lang);
    setTimeout(() => {}, 300);
});

example
I could delay a function in DOMContentLoaded by X amount of time, but making a connection  takes varying time and isn't exactly the answer I'm looking for.
I also am attempting to use Ethernet Offline Manager to get a response but I didn't get very far as I'd still be walking against the same problem.
ethernet_offline_manager_symbol

nevermind, found the solution. CrComLib.subscribeState can do wonders
